# How can I guess action name from url in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

For example I have a *url* generated by `something_path` or `something_url` methods. I need to know action name from that *url*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The routing system of Rails works two ways, it recognizes and builds URLs.
You need the recognize_path method, like the following example shows:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path('/mycontroller/myaction', :method => :get)
```

Assuming that the URL was generated with `something_path` or `something_url`, it returns:

```
{ :action => 'myaction', :controller => 'mycontroller' }
```

From which you are able to extract the action part.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to guess. You can run `rake routes` from the Terminal/Command Prompt to get a list of all the routes in your application. The output includes the HTTP method used, as well as the controller and action invoked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a view, you can use

- `action_name` to get access to the processing action
- `controller_name` to get access to the processing controller

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3:

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path("http://example.ltd/registrants")
=> => {:action=>"index", :controller=>"registrants"}
```

If you're in an engine, Events

```
Events::Engine.routes.recognize_path("/registrants")
=> {:action=>"index", :controller=>"events/registrants"}
```